# "MMC cannot create the snap in "

Tags: windows-sbs-2008, windows

I have Windows SBS 2008 R2, and when I try to open console manager or event viewer I get the message `MMC cannot create the snap in`. How do I fix this?

Comment: Duplicate of [MMC could not create the snap in](http://serverfault.com/questions/127995/mmc-could-not-create-the-snap-in)

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons for this error:

1. [Your path does not include %SystemRoot%\System32\WBEM](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/-snap-in-failed-to-initialize-error-message-when-you-open-microsoft-management-console-03b2432c-58d6-0c6c-41cb-c2d48cb6015d) Make sure you check the right path. If logged in to a standard account
2. Registry key gets corrupted or deleted: `HKLM\software\Microsoft\MMC\SnapIns\FX:{b05566ad-fe9c-4363-be05-7a4cbb7cb510}`. Export the key to text and check for corruption or export from another system with same OS version.

NOTE: I'm seeing this problem on Windows 11 Pro trying to create a console for managing Hyper-V and Active Directory Light. Answers are generic enough to apply to other Windows flavors.