# MMC could not create the snap in

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows

I have Windows SBS 2008 R2, and when I try to open console manager or event viewer I get the message `MMC cannot create the snap in`. How do I fix this?

Comment: Dup question: http://serverfault.com/questions/127254/mmc-cannot-create-the-snap-in

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/826282